# Checagem campo vazio e valor zero

Tags: c#, gridview

Abaixo tem dois exemplos dos meus códigos, eu tenho um text box peso que o usuário precisa colocar algum peso, e não pode ser 0. 
No primeiro código abaixo, ele faz a checagem porém, ele executa o restante do meu código onde eu comentei, o que não era para acontecer. Já que se for 0 ou em branco deve parar o código.
No segundo código ele funciona quando eu uso 0, porém se for em branco da erro por tentar transformar para int já que não existe nada no textbox.

Alguém tem uma solução para isso?

CÓDIGO 1

```
 protected void BT_Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TB_Peso.Text.Trim().ToString() == "")
            LBL_Peso.Visible = true;
        else
            LBL_Peso.Visible = false;
        {
            int zero = Int32.Parse(TB_Peso.Text);
            if (zero == 0)
                LBL_Peso.Visible = true;


            // meu código continua
        }
     }
```

CÓDIGO 2

```
 protected void BT_Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int zero = Int32.Parse(TB_Peso.Text);
        if (TB_Peso.Text.Trim().ToString() == "" || zero == 0)
            LBL_Peso.Visible = true;
        else
            LBL_Peso.Visible = false;
        {
```

Comment: Esse abre chaves, após `LBL_Peso.Visible = false;` existe de fato? Não era nem pra compilar com isso. Enfim, para corrigir seu erro de executar o resto do código, basta colocar todo ele dentro de um else.

Answer (score 1):

Tinha uma parte do seu código que estava fora das chaves do `ELSE`.

```
        protected void BT_Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TB_Peso.Text))
            LBL_Peso.Visible = true;
        else
        {
            LBL_Peso.Visible = false;

                int zero = Int32.Parse(TB_Peso.Text);
                if (zero == 0)
                    LBL_Peso.Visible = true;

            // meu código continua
        }
    }
```

Comment: Porém quando eu coloco 0 ele continua meu código, o que não deve acontecer. Como faço para resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
int zero = 0;            
int.TryParse(TB_Peso.Text, out zero);
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TB_Peso.Text) || zero == 0)
    LBL_Peso.Visible = true;
else
    LBL_Peso.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar o TryParse para checar se o que tem no textBox pode ser convertido para Int

Exemplo:

```
 //Cria uma variável int
 int number;

 //Pega o retorno, se vier, se vier true e por que pode ser convertido para int
 bool result = Int32.TryParse(TB_Peso.Text, out number); 
 if (result)
 {
    int zero = Int32.Parse(TB_Peso.Text);        
 }
 else
 {
     //Faz alguma coisa ou só retorna
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que seu codigo está ele só tem uma opção ou faz o que está no IF ou no ELSE.

Se você quer algo direfente disso faça assim:

protected void BT_Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TB_Peso.Text))
            LBL_Peso.Visible = true;
        else
        {
            LBL_Peso.Visible = false;

```
        int zero = Int32.Parse(TB_Peso.Text);
        if (zero == 0)
            LBL_Peso.Visible = true;
        else {  
            // meu código continua
        } 
    }
}
```

Talvez você consiga melhorar a construção assim:

```
protected void BT_Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TB_Peso.Text)) || ( Int32.Parse(TB_Peso.Text) == 0 )
        LBL_Peso.Visible = true;
    else
    {
        LBL_Peso.Visible = false;
        // meu código continua
    }
}
```

Deve resolver. Conforme ja postado acima pelo **dil_oliveira**.